# Widen a fibonacci flower using a for cycle

Tags: arrays, matlab, for-loop, plot, fibonacci

I was wondering in this example that I've used to practice for loops, I needed to change this code in order to change the image that looks like this, some basic golden angle plot:

[image: Fibonacci flower 1]

to this example

[image: Final image]

```
    phi = (sqrt(5)+1)/2;% Número áureo %Golden Number
golden_angle = 2*pi/phi;
max_angle = 10000;
theta = 1:golden_angle:max_angle;% ángulo %Angle
r = sqrt(theta);% radio %Radius
[x,y] = pol2cart(theta,r);% coordenadas polares a cartesianas %Polar to cartesian
figure
plot(x,y,'.','MarkerSize',10);axis off;
```

I know that the number next to 'MarkerSize' wides the flower petals, but I tried changing theta values in the array but with no particular result, only I’ve changed color but not the size. I also tried making these a for cycle, that creates circles as the golden flower petals, I think, but don't know how to implement it. But how to make them more and more small at the iteration goes?, and I think total number of petals is 2575.

```
for i = 1:10
   
    %plot(x,y,'.',x(i),y(i),'.','MarkerSize',10*abs(y(i)),'MarkerFaceColor','g')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `scatter` in place of `plot`: `scatter` allows to set the marker size as a parameter:

```
phi = (sqrt(5)+1)/2;% Número áureo %Golden Number
golden_angle = 2*pi/phi;
max_angle = 10000;
theta = 1:golden_angle:max_angle;% ángulo %Angle
r = sqrt(theta);% radio %Radius
marker_size = 10 * r / sqrt(max_angle);   % new
[x,y] = pol2cart(theta,r);% coordenadas polares a cartesianas %Polar to cartesian

figure
scatter(x,y,marker_size, 'fill'); axis off;               % new: scatter
```

`marker_size` data look good on table, increasing from 0 to 10 with `theta`.

However, on my Matlab (R2013b), the rendering is very gross.

Comment: You could change the color (white to blue) instead of the size.

Comment: @LuisMendo: true, will edit. However the rendering is still unsatisfying, at least for me.

Comment: @CrisLuengo: that would be nice. OP however wants output markers of increasing sizes moving out from the centre